# Как прочитать bmp в cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc

Очень хочу понять как преобразовать данный од чтобы он работал для открытия 1-битных bmp файлов. Вот нашёл такой код...

```
CFile File;
char *ReadBuffer; // Pointer to read buffer
char *OutputBuffer; // Pointer to output buffer
BITMAPFILEHEADER BmpFileHeader;
unsigned int BmpHeadSize;
char *BmpHeadPtr;

File.Open(FileName);
SrcFile.Read(&BmpFileHeader, sizeof(BmpFileHeader);
BmpHeadSize = BmpFileHeader.bfOffBits - sizeof(BmpFileHeader);
BmpHeadPtr = new char[BmpHeadSize];

File.Read(BmpHeadPtr, BmpHeadSize);
BmpInfoPtr = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)BmpHeadPtr;

ReadBuffer = new char[BmpInfoPtr->biSizeImage];

SrcFile.Read(ReadBuffer, BmpInfoPtr->biSizeImage);

OutputBuffer = new char[BmpInfoPtr->biSizeImage];
for (i = 0; i < IMAGE_HEIGHT; i++)
{
    //Use this line if the bitmap is 24 bit
        memcpy(&OutputBuffer[(IMAGE_HEIGHT - i - 1) * IMAGE_WIDTH * 3],
            &ReadBuffer[i * IMAGE_WIDTH * 3], IMAGE_WIDTH * 3);

}

memcpy(m_Ipl->imageData, OutputBuffer, BmpInfoPtr->biSizeImage);
```

И всё как бы норм работает, однако если считывать однобитные bmp, то тогда падает.
Кто нибудь может помочь разобраться как с моим вопросом?

Comment: Еще одно замечание - джентльмены заметили, что наличие программного кода , который можно просто взять из вопроса и запустить в отладчике, сильно увеличивает вероятность получить ответ. Чтобы запустить Ваш пример - нужны усилия.

Answer (score 0):

Если стоит задача загрузить изображение из файла (не важно какое), и Вы работаете с OpenCV, то логично использовать средства загрузки изображений непосредственно OpenCV, например по схеме:

```
char *fileName = "MyFile.bmp";
cv::Mat image = cv::imread( fileName )
if (image.data == 0)
{
    //Ошибка чтения 
    cerr << "Incorret input file name:   " << fileName  << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

//Обработка изображения
.....
```

Соответственно, все обработку тоже лучше делать средствами OpenCV

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,согласен , но всё же нет, задача заключается в преобразовании ReadBuffer в правильный вид. Например если этим кодом пытаться загрузить 1 битный битмап.

Comment: @Bobby Dillanl Тогда скорректируйте текст вопроса, дабы люди не теряли свое время